# Update unique/duplicate Data Records using single Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008 R3

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

I have a table **FileInfo** with below columns

```
**(SID int) Primary Key & AutoIncrement,
FileName varchar,
FilePath varchar,
fileExtn varchar,
CreatedDate smalldatetime,
Duplicate varchar,
LatestCopy varchar.**
```

the records in this are like shown below

```
1, 02-2511-510.pdf, C:\Desktop\02-2511-510.pdf, .pdf, 2000-10-12 00:00:00, NULL, NULL
2, 04-4648-500.doc, C:\Desktop\04-4648-500.doc, .doc, 2010-10-01 00:00:00, NULL, NULL
3, 02-2511-510.pdf, D:\Users\ers\02-2511-510.pdf, .pdf, 2000-11-13 00:00:00, NULL, NULL
4, 02-2511-510.pdf, E:\AGES\02-2511-510.pdf, .pdf, 2000-10-12 00:00:00, NULL, NULL
```

After running the stored procedure the table data should look like shown below

```
1, 02-2511-510.pdf, C:\Desktop\02-2511-510.pdf, .pdf, 2000-10-12 00:00:00, Y, N
2, 04-4648-500.doc, C:\Desktop\04-4648-500.doc, .doc, 2010-10-01 00:00:00, N, Y
3, 02-2511-510.pdf, D:\Users\ers\02-2511-510.pdf, .pdf, 2013-11-13 00:00:00, Y, Y
4, 02-2511-510.pdf, E:\AGES\02-2511-510.pdf, .pdf, 2000-10-12 00:00:00, Y, N
```

1. Basically i need to find the duplicates based on **FileName** column.
2. If the file occurs multiple times set Duplicate column as 'Y'
3. Then find the LatestCopy of the file based on CreatedDate and set the LatestCopy value to Y

I am able to write a stored procedure to find the duplicates and update the column Duplicate as Y/N. I also want to include the marking of LatestCopy in the same stored procedure. How can i do that.

My apologies if i have made any mistake, as i am learning SQL now.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your Current Data**

```
╔═════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ SID ║    FileName     ║           FilePath           ║ fileExtn ║     CreatedDate     ║ Duplicate ║ LatestCopy ║
╠═════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║   1 ║ 02-2511-510.pdf ║ C:\Desktop\02-2511-510.pdf   ║ .pdf     ║ 2000-10-12 00:00:00 ║ NULL      ║ NULL       ║
║   2 ║ 04-4648-500.doc ║ C:\Desktop\04-4648-500.doc   ║ .doc     ║ 2010-10-01 00:00:00 ║ NULL      ║ NULL       ║
║   3 ║ 02-2511-510.pdf ║ D:\Users\ers\02-2511-510.pdf ║ .pdf     ║ 2000-11-13 00:00:00 ║ NULL      ║ NULL       ║
║   4 ║ 02-2511-510.pdf ║ E:\AGES\02-2511-510.pdf      ║ .pdf     ║ 2000-10-12 00:00:00 ║ NULL      ║ NULL       ║
╚═════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

**Update Queries**

1) Update Where Data is Duplicated

```
    ;WITH Updateables
    AS
    (
      SELECT * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [FileName] ORDER BY [FileName])
DESC)
      FROM Table_Name
    )
    UPDATE Updateables 
    SET Duplicate = 'Y'
    WHERE [FileName] IN (SELECT [FileName] 
                    FROM Updateables WHERE rn > 1 )
```

2) Update to `Y` the latest Version

```
;WITH Updateables
AS
(
  SELECT * , rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [FileName] ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)
  FROM Table_Name
)
UPDATE Updateables 
SET LatestCopy = 'Y'
WHERE [SID] IN (SELECT [SID]
                FROM Updateables WHERE rn2 = 1)
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ SID ║    FileName     ║           FilePath           ║ fileExtn ║     CreatedDate     ║ Duplicate ║ LatestCopy ║
╠═════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║   1 ║ 02-2511-510.pdf ║ C:\Desktop\02-2511-510.pdf   ║ .pdf     ║ 2000-10-12 00:00:00 ║ Y         ║ NULL       ║
║   2 ║ 04-4648-500.doc ║ C:\Desktop\04-4648-500.doc   ║ .doc     ║ 2010-10-01 00:00:00 ║ NULL      ║ Y          ║
║   3 ║ 02-2511-510.pdf ║ D:\Users\ers\02-2511-510.pdf ║ .pdf     ║ 2000-11-13 00:00:00 ║ Y         ║ Y          ║
║   4 ║ 02-2511-510.pdf ║ E:\AGES\02-2511-510.pdf      ║ .pdf     ║ 2000-10-12 00:00:00 ║ Y         ║ NULL       ║
╚═════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

## [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/146bf/1)